# Android Studio will not build (Access Denied error for config.ini)

Tags: android-studio

When I try to build the default Android Studio Hello World app, I receive the following error:

> Cannot reload AVD list: C:\Users\mark.android\avd\AVDcheck1.avd\config.ini (Access is denied

When I press "OK", the error dialog immediately reappears, so I have to force Android Studio to quit (I'm using Win 7, and running as Admin doesn't help).
Edit: I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0

Comment: right click on config.ini to get properties dialog and find the access flags and tell us what is there

Comment: @FredGrott All permissions are set to "Allow" for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my `.AndroidStudio` folder and reinstalled Android Studio. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem like you but solve it just by

1. **Close** Android Studio
2. Run it again as administrator (**Run as administrator**) .

[image: Run as administrator]